# FileNotFoundException when picking image from Gallery

Tags: java, android, image, media, filenotfoundexception

I'm building an Android Application that has a button, and when the user click it he has to pick an image, from gallery or camera, that will be sent to my server.
But when I try to test it in the emulator, when I submit I encountered the following error:

```
12-30 17:44:14.435: W/System.err(4216): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A14: open failed: ENOENT 
(No such file or directory)
```

The error is there:

```
FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(this.image, "image/*");
```

And `this.image` is the image that was picked from the gallery.

Comment: Have you tried in a Device instead of an emulator?

Comment: yes, my image isn't sended, but i can't see the log, because my Android device is not recognized by Eclipse :(

Comment: What device is yours?

Comment: Wiko Iggy.. is not so popular

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this in one of my apps. Try this to see if it works.

This is the code to open the gallery to pick an image...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/jpg");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Make sure the following method is in your class because it is called after the gallery activity finishes...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap selectedImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

now you can do whatever you want with the **Bitmap selectedImage**